# Trying to calculate a score using a math formula in Java

Tags: java, math

I am trying to calculate a score in Java using a formula. I am having trouble with translating it to Java code.

Formula:  = 3 ^ ( ( log2( points/3) ) + 1)

points = the input.

I currently have this piece of code, but I am not getting the result I would like:

```
int score = 3 ^ (int)(Math.pow(Math.log(12 / 3), 2) + 1);
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and possibly give me a snippet of how it should be? The result should be 27 with 12 as input. Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:

```
Input 3 = 3
Input 6 = 9
Input 12 = 27
Input 24 = 81
Input 48 = 243
Input 96 = 729
Input 192 = 2187
etc.
```

Comment: It would help others help you if you say exactly what output you are getting and what you expected it to be. That said, my advice is to use floating point numbers (`float` or `double`) instead of integers throughout. You might be getting something like 7.999999 instead of 8 or something like that.

Comment: Note that `^` is the bitwise xor operator.

Comment: @RobertDodier Updated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is:

```
int score = (int) Math.pow(3, Math.log(points/3.0) / Math.log(2) + 1);
```

- ^ in Java is the bit-wise XOR operator, you need to use `Math.pow` instead for power
- log2(x) refers to "base 2" logarithm, there's no builtin function for it but you can you can compute it with log(x)/log(2)

You may want to use `Math.round` instead of cast to `(int)` in case the output is slightly off.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in this code, the main one though is that you are using the ^ operator for power, the ^ operator for "bitwise exclusive OR",

Another mistake is that you used `Math.log()` as if it's in base 2, even though it's in base e.

Now let's rewrite the code again:

First we want to get log in base 2 of n, to do so, we use the formula:

> logb(n) = loge(n) / loge(b)

So to get log in base 2 of 12/3 we'd write:
`Math.log(12/3)/Math.log(2)`

Now the rest of the operation to get the number in the power is easy:
`(int) (Math.log(12/3) / Math.log(2) + 1)`

The last bit is using the `Math.pow()` function properly, if we want 3^n we'd need to type in `Math.pow(3, n)`.

So the final code would be: `Math.pow(3, (int) (Math.log(12/3) / Math.log(2) + 1) )`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to split it step by step for you. Please check the snippet below.

```
public class Score {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int points = 12;
        int dividedPoints = points / 3;
        int log2Value = log2(dividedPoints);
        int k = log2Value + 1;
        int score = (int) Math.pow(3, k);
        System.out.println("final score is = " + score);
    }

    public static int log2(int N) {
        // using log() method
        int result = (int) (Math.log(N) / Math.log(2));
        System.out.println("log2 Value is = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

It would produce the following output

```
log2 Value is = 2
final score is = 27
```